# If statement on for a phrase rather then a specific title?

Tags: javascript, html, css, if-statement

I'm currently working on a cms that will have an alert appear on multiple pages. I am currently using an if statement to have the alert appear only a page with a specific page title. Is there a way of generalizing it and having it appear on all articles with the word "Test" in the title?

At the moment my logic is if `@pageTitle === "Test Article Two` display....

I tried doing `@pageTitle === "Test"` but that only shows on the article that has the title Test rather then other titles with the word Test in them.

Here is my code :

```
<script>
    if(document.title === "Test Article Two") {
        document.body.classList.add("show-alert");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `/Test/.test(document.title)`

Comment: You can do `if document.title.indexOf('Test') > -1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods -

Regex, case sensitive:

```
if (/Test/.test(document.title)) { ... }
```

Regex, case insensitive

```
if (/test/i.test(document.title)) { ... }
```

indexOf, case sensitive, (fastest)

```
if (document.title.indexOf("Test") !== -1) { ... }
```

includes (ES6), case sensitive

```
if (document.title.includes("Test")) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the JavaScript [string method includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes): `if (document.title.includes('Test'))`.